# __EVENTTARGET Contains Invalid Control ID

Tags: asp.net, events, postback

Googled variations of the title and everything was related to a null value.

I have an issue where the return value from Page.Request.Params["__EVENTTARGET"] duplicates the unique id of the control.

`ctl00$MainContent$ActivityTabset$TabNewActivity$cbxActivityCode$ctl00$MainContent$ActivityTabset$TabNewActivity$cbxActivityCode`

`cbxActivityCode.UniqueID` returns

`ctl00$MainContent$ActivityTabset$TabNewActivity$cbxActivityCode`

The following is the code that fails in the comparison. It is in the Page_Load event, and is the only code to execute right now if it is a postback.

```
string controlName = Page.Request.Params["__EVENTTARGET"];
if (cbxActivityCode.UniqueID == controlName)
{
     ConfigureActivityUnits();
}
```

Here is the definition of the control

```
<obout:ComboBox ID="cbxActivityCode" runat="server" 
                DataSourceID="ObjectDataSourceDAOActivity"
                FilterType="StartsWith" EmptyText="Select..." 
                AutoPostBack="true" 
                OnSelectedIndexChanged="cbxActivityCode_SelectedIndexChanged"
                AllowCustomText="false" AutoValidate="true" DataValueField="Id" 
                DataTextField="Description" EnableViewState="true" 
                OpenOnFocus="true" MenuWidth="425" AllowEdit="False" 
                Width="300px">
</obout:ComboBox>
```

I am new to ASP.net and am wondering if it is possible one of the control attributes is causing this behavior?

Is it possibly a bug with the control?

Are there hooks in ASP.net where someone can manipulate a value which will effect Page.Request.Params["__EVENTTARGET"]? (This is a big messy legacy system, and I have no prior developers as a resource.)

If not any of the above, anyone have any ideas as to what could be causing this?

Comment: Please post the code where the `"return value duplicates the id of the control."`.

Comment: @Karl Thanks for the edit, you taught me how to properly format code in questions.

Comment: Have you watched the request to the server to see if there are two instances of `__VIEWSTATE`, `__EVENTTARGET` in the request to the server? From what I remember of other people having problems like this is that there are multiple `<form>` objects in the page.

Comment: I have not, would I have to use Fiddler, or is there a method of doing that in VS 2010?

Comment: Fiddler will give you the most amount of information in one place, but the browser developer tools will also (`Firebug`, `IE F12 Tools`, or `Chrome Developer Tools`).

Comment: Looked at parsed form data using Chrome Developer tools. There was a single instance of **__EVENTTARGET** which has the incorrect `ctl00$MainContent$ActivityTabset$TabNewActivity$cbxActivityCode$ctl00$MainContent$ActivityTabset$TabNewActivity$cbxActivityCode`. There is a **__VIEWSTATE** and a **__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED** section. Curiously the **__VIEWSTATE** appears to be encrypted, and the **__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED** is unencrypted and contains the correct unique id for the control `ctl00$MainContent$ActivityTabset$TabNewActivity$cbxActivityCode`.

Comment: Is this issue isolated to this page or is it rife throughout the application?

Comment: I would have to test, this is the first time the __EVENTTARGET variable has been used in the codebehind. Would events fail to execute for controls that were returning an invalid __EVENTTARGET?

Comment: Also, from an earlier comment, there is only a single form defined for the page. It is actually in the master page, the child page nor any of the contained user controls have a form defined.